# Upgrade Graph SDK to 5.0 - Reference to type IAuthenticationProvider claims it is defined in Microsoft.Graph.Core, but cannot be found

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Steps:
Create sample project from template in VS2022 (.NET 7) with authentication and Graph -> works

Update Graph Core to 3.01 and Graph to. 5.1 ->

`Could not load type 'Microsoft.Graph.IAuthenticationProviderOption' from assembly 'Microsoft.Graph.Core`

Please help

Comment: I can only guess but there is no support for Graph v5. https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/2097

Comment: As mentioned above by user2250152, as it is not supported as of now, but there is Temporary solution: https://gist.github.com/ashelopukho/5b00944c7744ebb4f9baa348e86f7e0e

Answer (score 5):

I've managed to get it to work after replacing dependency **Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph** with **Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient**.

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient/Readme.md

Comment: Man, you've saved me 

Comment: note - see also https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1695 , https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/2097  . To fix the compilation error I found that as well as installing Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient, I also had to uninstall Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph.  Having both installed still gave the error.

Comment: can you provide more information on this answer, maybe an example ?